# URL API (JSon) store in MySql

Tags: mysql, json, api

i want to store API result in database
i am new to this API php coding things,

```
    <?php
$account_id = 1122;
$api = "http://url&account_id";
$json = file_get_contents($api);
print_r($json);
?>
```

here is the output

```
{"status":"ok","count":1,"meta":{"count":1},"data":{"1122":{"statistics":{"all":{"wins":112,"losses":118},"xp":721},"nickname":"nickie"}}}
```

now i  want to store data in variables and as well want to show in Tables.
for saving it in variables i am using this method.

```
$nickname = $decoded->{'data'}->{$account_id}->{'nickname'};
$max_xp = $decoded->{'data'}->{$account_id}->{'statistics'}->{'xp'};
```

how can i show all data in tables. or anywhere on main body page.

sorry for my bad poor programming, i am trying to so learn it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's really difficult to answer your question because it's not clear what your code is, what you expect to happen, and what's actually happening. Please edit your question and clarify it.

Comment: sorry 1st time posted a question so my mistake to clarify it as per requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case if I understand correctly, it is necessary to create an HTML form you with two text boxes, you can later send this form in a PHP page that can retrieve the values of these input fields and create the URL for the API:

1. An HTML page

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Your page title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <form method="post" action="/your/php/file">
        <div>
          <label for="name" />
          <input type="text" name="username" id="name" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="location" />
          <input type="text" name="location" id="location" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

2. A PHP page

```html
<?php
  

  if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['location']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['location'])) {
    $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
    $location = htmlspecialchars($_POST['location']);

    $account_id = 1122;

    $api = "http://url?account_id&username={$username}&location={$location}";

    $json = file_get_contents($api);
  
    //now you have result as associative array
    $result = json_decode($json, true);

    //you can do what you want now
  }

  
?>
```

Comment: Perfect i did exactly that way and it worked super good. thanks  is thr any way i can store array directly to MySQL database and retrieve any information whatever i want from there, like i am getting alot of things from this api and storing it in php variables, and then calling it in where i need. is this right way to do ? or any other easy way too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `json_decode` your results like this:

```html
<?php
  $account_id = 1122;

  $api = "http://url&account_id";

  $json = file_get_contents($api);
  
  //now you have result as associative array
  $result = json_decode($json, true);

  //print_r($result); 

  $nickname = $result['data'][$account_id]['nickname'];
?>
```

try and tell me what

Comment: omg thanks for fast reply wasnt expecting that.:) ok it gave me exact nickname from API. now going back to google and how to make a 2 inputs form, i want to pass 2 inputs in a form 1- User Name 2- Location, and pass those inputs to api url, like hxxp://europe.url&account_id so it can grab data from that location for specific entered nickname or username.

Comment: this answer was useful? can you raise the flag to allow people who have the same problem as you ending up easily?

Comment: and about your question, can you explain me correctly what final format of the url do you need for your API? eg: `http://url&param1=a&param2=b`

Comment: Yes it did helped me, i tried earlier and now again to raise the flag for answer, but it saying need 15 reputation to do it i guess.

Comment: URL for API is like this hxxps://url/application_id=demo&account_id=demo

Comment: can you try with my second answer below: